# Set Bitrate for the stream audio in android

Tags: android, media-player

I have a simple android app, thar stream online radio, everything is OK, but the client want the app has 2 options, 128 kbp/s and 38 kbp/s. how I can set bitrate to the MediaPlayer Class in asdroid?

this is my pla action:

```
public void actionPlay(View view) {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html#adaptive-playback) may help you

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the documentation using `prepareAsync()` is better from streams. If you use `prepare()`, you will block it until enough data is buffered.

> mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

Refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync%28%29). 
As for setting the bit rate there is no mention of it in the official documentation.
Perhaps you need to go NDK to realize it and that will require lots of work..